# iTunes select/create library dialogue doesn't show

Tags: itunes

I have tried the advice given on here to restore iTunes from backup but I don't get the dialogue box pop up which asks if I want to create library or choose library.

Answer (score 3):

For OS X: Immediately after clicking the iTunes icon, leave <kbd>Option</kbd> (<kbd>Alt</kbd>) pressed. The dialog should appear.

For Windows: Keep <kbd>Shift</kbd> pressed and click the iTunes icon. When the dialog appears, you can release the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key.